# Is it reasonable to isolate iPhone/iPad event handlers in separate .m files and then #import them in the viewcontroller @implementation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, import, viewcontroller

Total newbie here on iPhone/iPad development, so forgive me if this seems like a strange question.

Given that most objects (or group of objects) in a view within a `UIViewController` need to have an event callback defined, would it seem reasonable to group the callbacks into separate .m files and then `#import` them after the `@implementation` of the viewcontroller?

This way, the standard methods, i`nitWithNibName:`, `-viewDidLoad`, `shouldAutoRotateInterfaceOrientation:`, `didReceiveMemoryWarning:`, `-viewDidUnload` and dealloc (as provided by Xcode) would be the only methods defined in your viewcontroller.m file.  The viewcontroller.m file would not become this monolithic monstrosity of event callbacks and would be simpler to maintain.  I'm thinking you put them after your `@synthesize` outlets.

Thoughts?

Comment: After spending a month learning about iPhone/iPad development, the majority of code that I've seen, and presumably Apple developers code the same way, uses the single viewcontroller.m file.  Add the pragma statements and it looks like the simplest and best approach for the time being is Darren's.  I do like Justin's approach and when/if I get better at this, I might implement his way of doing things.  Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it may seem like you are making a monolithic file, the ViewController is really the place for all of this stuff.  If you do what you propose (which is entirely possible), you will end up with a bunch of files that do little.

One way to keep organized in a large file is to separate groups of methods with pragma marks like so:

```
#pragma mark lifecycle methods

-(void)dealloc{}
-(id)init{}
-(id)initWithCoder:

#pragma mark target-action

-(id)doSomethingAction:(id)sender{}
-(id)doSometingElse:(id)sender{}
```

Xcode will parse the pragma marks and group the methods for you in the pull down item bar for easy access.  Notice that the methods in this list are also listed in alphabetical order.

Comment: darren, this might be a compromise between the thoughts I had and your belief that the ViewController.m is the place for this code.

Answer (score 0):

here's an illustration of one alternative, this uses an objc category:

```
/* File: Header A */
@interface MONViewController : NSViewController
{
    unsigned anIvar;
}

@property (nonatomic, readonly) unsigned anIvar;

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle;
- (void)dealloc;

- (void)viewDidLoad;
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation;

/* (continued) */

@end

/* File: Header A or Header B, depending on how you want to organize it */

@interface MONViewController (EventCallbacks)

- (IBAction)triviaButtonWasPressed:(id)sender;

/* (continued) */

@end

/* File: Imp A */
@implementation MONViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibName bundle:(NSBundle *)bundle { /* ... */ }
- (void)dealloc { /* ... */ }
- (unsigned)anIvar { /* ... */ }

- (void)viewDidLoad { /* ... */ }
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation { /* ... */ }

/* (continued) */

@end

/* File: Imp A or Imp B, depending on how you want to organize it */

@implementation MONViewController (EventCallbacks)

- (IBAction)triviaButtonWasPressed:(id)sender { /* ... */ }

/* (continued) */

@end
```

fortunately, the compiler verifies that you've defined all your declarations when a category is defined, as is performed in a class. some things must be defined in the proper class implementation, such as protocols.

be careful if you divide this into a ton of smaller files - your build times can really suffer. also, it's somewhat inevitable in this case (since your subclassing) but scalability issues in this regard should serve as reminders that your interfaces/classes are attempting to do too much, and should be divided into smaller components. good luck!

Comment: Justin,  I'm going to have to look at this closer to get my head around it.  So if I understand this correctly, using the (EventCallbacks) appended to MONViewController, I can separate out the default callbacks from my UI callbacks, put them in separate .m and .h files if I choose, and everything will work, and because the Imp A and Imp B files both reference the @implementation MONViewController, I still have access to my outlets? or do I need to be cognizant of which @interface I define the @property(s) in?  Looks like I *DO* need to be aware of where I define them.

Comment: yes, the compiler will warn you if you have not defined a method or property where it was declared. so... `triviaButtonWasPressed:` and everything declared in the interface/category must be defined in the corresponding @implementation. you may declare properties in categories - assuming IB can locate those headers (e.g., they are in your project and parse-able) the actions and outlets should be available. caveat: the compiler fails to warn or check if you've defined the same method in multiple interfaces; so you could define viewDidLoad in both implementations aaaand this is probably UB. silly

Answer (score 0):

The issue I see with separating them out is that most of the callbacks will have to work with class local variables, and it's just handier to have them declared in the corresponding header file for the @implementation you are working with.  To me it makes more sense to keep event handling stuff in the view controller, and move any other functionality left out into some separate file...

But anything you break out may have to use the same class instance variables as well, meaning that you may have to make some class variables public you might not otherwise.

The category breakout Justin presented solves that issue but to me, using class instance variables you cannot technically "see" just seems weird.

Comment: Kendall, Since the .m files are #import'd, and not compiled separately, they would have access to all the variables that are in the viewcontroller.m file.  They're acting just like .h files, only not mucking up the rest of the viewcontroller.m file.

Comment: I know they have access, it's just that it's bad form to have a category that uses class internal variables.  And also annoying when you can't just switch to the corresponding header file to see them right away (when you are in the implementation file for the protocol I don't think the XCode header toggle command will know to jump to the "real" interface file)

Comment: Good point.  Thanks.  I think the proposal that Justin came up with might be the way to go, but thank you for your input and time that you took to answer my question.